# Why doesn't optical path difference occur when light from two coherent sources pass through a lens?

Tags: optics, interference

I guess, for a convex lens I might say that the marginal rays travel a longer path but spend a shorter time inside the lens, while the opposite of that happens in case of paraxial rays. That can be an explanation for the same optical path, but what about a concave lens? For a concave lens, the marginal rays actually travel a longer path and also spend more time inside the lens. I might be wrong in my conjecture, and even if I'm right, I'd like a quantitative explanation.

Comment: Intersting to note that all rays take the same time to reach a common focus point.

Answer (score 1):

on a concave lense you have to measure the path from the source to the virtual image, not the real image. As you can see here:

Path A is longuer than C and C is longuer than B.

[image]

And accordingly the lens is thicker for B than C, and thicker for C than A.

Comment: May I ask for a quantitative discussion?

Comment: I may if first you find the quantitative discussion for convex lenses.